# Populate collection from array of JSONs nested in a model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model called subject.
One property of subject is called receivers and consists of an array of objects.
I want to create a collection from the array of objects.

In the subject view I do this:

```
var receivers = this.model.get('receivers');
```

And everything looks good in the console. The receivers variable now consists of five objects, as expected.

Then I do this:

```
var receiversCollection = new App.Collections.Receivers( receivers );
```

Now, when I examine receiversCollection it contains just two strange objects:

```
child {length: 2, models: Array[2], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - Addititonal information included below.

These are my definitions:

```
App.Models.Receiver = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        location: '',
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null
    }
});

App.Collections.Receivers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Receiver
});
```

This is what the five receivers looks like in the console:

```
0: Object
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
email: "info@example.com"
first_name: "Adam"
id: "1"
last_name: "Bertilsson"
location: "Stockholm"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "2013-04-16 07:33:26"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
email: "info@example.com"
first_name: "Sven"
id: "2"
last_name: "Svensson"
location: "Uppsala"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
email: "info@example.com"
first_name: "Adam"
id: "1"
last_name: "Bertilsson"
location: "Stockholm"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "2013-04-16 07:33:26"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
email: "info@example.com"
first_name: "Adam"
id: "1"
last_name: "Bertilsson"
location: "Stockholm"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "2013-04-16 07:33:26"
__proto__: Object
4: Object
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
email: "info@example.com"
first_name: "Sven"
id: "2"
last_name: "Svensson"
location: "Uppsala"
pivot: Object
updated_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

This is what the receiversCollection looks like in the console:

```
_byId: Object
  1: child
  2: child
  c56: child
  c57: child
  __proto__: Object
length: 2
models: Array[2]
  0: child
  1: child
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Surrogate
```

Comment: Post your JSON and maybe the definition of `App.Collections.Receivers`.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question and included the definitions and what the objects look like.

Comment: Can you post the entire json for the array you are expecting.I mean all the 5 models

Comment: Yup, that was what I asked :) ie, the content of the `receivers` var.

Comment: Right..It is difficult to say having a look at a single object. For now everything looks fine ... :)

Comment: Ok, have now copy/pasted the result of console.log(receivers).

Comment: Hmm, is the problem perhaps that the same model id occurs multiple times?

Comment: Seems like that is the problem. My application adds a receiver object in the receivers array each time the subject is sent to a receiver. The same receiver can exist multiple times in the receivers array. But it seems like Backbone won't accept the same model multiple times in the collection.

Comment: Same model will be accepted by your collection `provided the id is unique`.

Comment: Yeah, I have to replace the ids someway, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is because of the **Duplicated Id's .**

```
Id's must be unique..
```

As the collection is created , it skims thru the `id's` , as the first 2 models have `unique id still not present` in the collection , they are added.

The others are ignored as the models with that id's are already present in the collection.

Try to edit the id's of the models and voila , you will see 5 models in the collection.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make each receivers pivot.id to become the receiver id in the collection? The pivot.id seems to be unique (since it is the id column in the many-to-many database table).

Comment: Generally idAttribute is , set to an attribute in the model. But since pivot itself is an object .. I am not sure if that will work.. Try and let me know that . Never tried that before

Comment: I did this inside the model App.Models.Receiver: initialize: function() { var pivot = this.get('pivot'); this.set('id', pivot.id); }

Comment: Actually I also did this.set('created_at', pivot.created_at) since I want the datetime when the subject was sent (= when the entry in the pivot was created), not when the receiver was created.